# how to make a php file work more than once

Tags: php

I have a little generator, It generate a random  phone numbers and here is my code.

```
<?php
    limit_phone = 8; //limit phone number
    $randomphone = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789", $limit_phone)), 0, $limit_phone); //random numbers
    $randomphonecomp = array('010','011','012','015'); // company
    $randomphonecomp1 = array_rand($randomphonecomp);
    $phonefinaal = $randomphonecomp[$randomphonecomp1] . $randomphone;
    echo $phonefinaal. "<br>";
?>
```

What I want is,  when i run this file to work more than one time, means that i want this file to generate  automatically with out stop until i stop the page from the browser

Comment: You could put your code in a function, and make the function return the $phonefinaal variable. From there you could call the function many time using a loop. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php and http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php for examples but what I understand is you may want to have a look at client code to repeatly call the php page

Comment: can you make it to understand you

Comment: as @Ggg said use function which print some content on page and make nested for loop and add sleep because without that it will very fast and probably kill your browser

Comment: @daremachine can you edit my code and send it to me i am beginner in php

Comment: The code you need to add is the Javascript on your web page.

Comment: As other suggested - you could decide on a page size (say 20 number) and make your PHP code download one page per request. Then put some code at the browser end that requests PHP to download the data a page at a time. Its not advisable to make an infinite loop at the PHP end. If you are not experienced with JavaScript then maybe ask a friend who is. The needed code is easy.  People at this site will help you to fix programs, but not do all the work for you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop to generate specified number of phone numbers, Don't use an infinite loop, it will kill your browser and you will not able to stop the loop.

```
<?php
$total_numbers = 100;
$i=1;
while($i<=$total_numbers){
    $limit_phone = 8; //limit phone number
    $randomphone = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789", $limit_phone)), 0, $limit_phone); //random numbers
    $randomphonecomp = array('010','011','012','015'); // company
    $randomphonecomp1 = array_rand($randomphonecomp);
    $phonefinaal = $randomphonecomp[$randomphonecomp1] . $randomphone;
    echo $phonefinaal. "<br>";
$i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: can i make a time sleep between each generate

Comment: If you need ultra more numbers, you can do that. Otherwise if it is 100 ~ 1000 numbers, you don't need it. If you are going to make many more numbers, you need to increase php max execution time in your server.

Comment: can you give me your facebook profile i want to contact with you

Comment: use this lahirutm@gmail.com, i am not very active member in facebook

Answer (score 0):

As @bcperth said, you most likely need to generate phone numbers using Javascript in the page, it could be something like this:

```js
var divNumbers = document.getElementById("numbers")
var btnStop = document.getElementById("stop")

function generate() {
  var randomphone = ""
  for(var i = 0; i < 8; ++i) randomphone += Math.floor(Math.random()*10)
  var randomcomp = ['010', '011', '012', '015'][Math.floor(Math.random()*4)] + ""
  divNumbers.innerHTML += randomcomp + randomphone + "<br>"
}

generate() // first generated number
var intervalGen = setInterval(generate, 2000) // others generated number

function stop() {
  clearInterval(intervalGen)
}

btnStop.addEventListener("click", stop)
```

```css
#stop {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<span id="stop"> STOP </span>
<div id="numbers"></div>
```

Documentation:

- [setInterval() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)
- [Math.random() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)
- [Math.floor() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)

Comment: thanks but  i want to use curl in php can java script help ?